# view output of xsl in browser

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file.I want to change some styles of xml elements by xsl.so I have one xsl file too.then I want to see the changes in my browser,but I dont know how can I do this?

xml file:(test.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test2.xsl"?>


<root>
    <Text Style='style1'></Text>
    <Text Style='style2'></Text>
</root>
```

xsl file:(test.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="style1">
        <xsl:attribute name="Font">Arial</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Bold">true</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Color">Red</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="style2">
        <xsl:attribute name="Font">Sans</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Italic">true</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:template match="Text[@Style='style1']">
        <xsl:copy use-attribute-sets="style1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()!='Style']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Text[@Style='style2']">
        <xsl:copy use-attribute-sets="style2">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()!='Style']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place `test.xml` and `test.xsl` in the same directory and then load `test.xml` in your browser - the `?xml-stylesheet` directive at the beginning will cause the xsl to be loaded and executed by the browser.

Having said that, your XSL applied to your XML test file produces this output:

```
<Text Font="Arial" Bold="true" Color="Red"></Text>
<Text Font="Sans" Italic="true"></Text>
```

that is not valid HTML, so you won't see anything in your browser.

To see some output try using this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="Text[@Style='style1']">
    <p style="font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; color: red">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Text[@Style='style2']">
    <p style="font-family: Sans-Serif; font-style: italic">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that generates `p` HTML tags with a style attribute. Note also that you need to add some text to apply the styles to in your XML test file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test2.xsl"?>
<root>
  <Text Style='style1'>Text in style 1</Text>
  <Text Style='style2'>Text in style 2</Text>
</root>
```

Comment: Isn't any way to see the output in the browser?I want to see style1 by this properties(Arial,Bold,Red).

Comment: When I try this with files on the local hard drive, I get a an Unsafe attempt to load URL on Chrome :(